# How to Add Total Count Stock of Color and Size (PHP)

Tags: php

I’m trying to achieve to put stock count for each colour and size for my e-commerce website, I already have the quantity inserted in the database, just need to add all the quantity by using the foreach statement. Sorry, I’m New in Javascript, any advice or help will be appreciated.

This is my Codes

This is the quantity that I did:

```
public function getQuantityAttribute($quantity)

{

    if (empty($quantity)) {

    return "<span class='extra-price out'>(Out of Stock)</span>";

} 

    return "<span class='extra-price'>({$quantity} left)</span>";

}
```

This is the code I’m trying to add each quantity:

```
public function totalQuantity($quantity)

{

$totalQuantity = $quantity++;

return "<span class='extra-price'>+({$totalQuantity})</span>";

}
```

This is the code declared to show the quantity:

```
{!! $value->quantity; !!}
```

Thank in Advance :)
If anyone can give me any tips of adding a total count of stock of colour and size I will appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workflow here is a little unclear. From what I can tell, you are wanting to print one one more than the quantity value you are passing in. You also mention both a database and JavaScript without addressing how they relate to the work being done here.

If you are wanting the "Total Quantity" to be the "Sum of all quantities", you will either need the "Total Quantity" to be instantiated against the object, or you will need the `totalQuantity()` function to gather and return the amounts from your database.

Consider the following:

```
class StockRecord {

    public float $totalqty;

    public function updateTotalQty(float $quantity): float {
        return $this->$totalqty += $quantity;
    }

    public function getTotalQty(): float {
        return $this->$totalqty;
    }

    public function printQtyAttribute(float $qty): string {
        $display = $qty . ' remaining';
        $class = '';
        if (empty($qty)) {
            $display = 'Out of Stock';
            $class = ' out'; 
        }
        return "<span class='extra-price" .$class. "'>(" . $display . " left)</span>";       
    }
}
```

The key difference here is that your StockRecord class allows you to do the summation as a part of the instantiated object workflow. This will allow you to keep track of this a a well-scoped variable in the class. I am not sure what structure you have exactly around this in regards to class, but a rough outline would be the "getter/setter/updater" paradigm around a publicly available variable. Let me know if I can clarify this any further!

Comment: there should be no! beside empty because it will say if not empty it will show out of stock right? should remove ! right?

Comment: Great Explanation, please help me declare it like I did in my question above I declared my quantity, this is the code {!! $value->quantity; !!}, thank u and have a great day :)

Comment: What would you mean by “declare it”? You can instantiate the class by assigning a variable like `$var = new StockRecord()`, then using the $var->getQuantity() Call where you need to access it